# python - sort csv files by columns, while preserving the header

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I imported the csv into python, and now I have a nested list that looks like this.

```
data = [['header1,'header2','header3'...], [1,2,3...], [a,b,c...] ]
```

So the first line is the header row, and the rest are the actual data. I want to sort the data using the following code:

```
data = sorted(data, key = lambda x: x[1]) #-> sorts data by the 2nd header
```

But when I do this, the code sorts the header row too, and my header is at the middle of somewhere in my data. How can I preserve my header in the first row, while sorting the rest?
I've seen some code that does this by using operator.itemgetter(), but I don't want to do this way

Comment: im sure you could just remove the header and store it as another variable and then just add it to the front of the sorted data

Comment: i've tried that, and for some reason I had an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort a slice of the array like:

```
data = [['header1','header2','header3'], 
        [1, 2, 3], 
        [2, 3, 4], 
        [5, 6, 7], 
        [3, 4, 5],
        [7, 8, 9], 
        [6, 3, 4] 
]

data[1:] = sorted(data[1:], key = lambda x: x[0])
```

This takes everything from the first element on,sorts it, and reassigns it to the same slice of the array.

data now is:

```
 [['header1', 'header2', 'header3'], 
 [1, 2, 3], 
 [2, 3, 4], 
 [3, 4, 5], 
 [5, 6, 7], 
 [6, 3, 4], 
 [7, 8, 9]
 ]
```

Comment: I might even recommend `data[1:].sort(key = lambda x: x[1])`... it may reduce the memory footprint on large datasets.  (OP has `x[1]` in question, not `x[0]`)

Answer (score 0):

sorted(data[1:], key=lambda x: x[1])

Comment: Can you add more of an explanation please